# Diaplaying unique element into the html table through JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to display **unique elements** of already binded data in that html table by using **JQuery or JavaScript**. Displaying unique value means that **mearging the cells** having same value in the rows. The table data is **dynamic** but the structure is fix.

So, here is given table:

[image: Given Table Data]

Here, I need to merge the Red colored cells as shown below.

And the required table is:

[image: Required Table]

So, I need to achieve **this cell merging** through **Jquery or javascript**. As this table is created with HTML table and the data is already binded in it. By using this binded data I need to achieve the reqiured table. I need to merge more columns like this.

I have tried some coding but it is not working correctly. The code is:

```
jQuery('tr.tblRow').each(function(i, obj)
{   
     current_name = jQuery(obj).text();

     var current_name_arr = current_name.split(/\t|\n| /);

     /* check for repeated names */
     if (current_name_arr[22] == last_selected_compNo)
     {
          jQuery("td.headingSpas:contains('" + current_name_arr[22] + "')").each(function(index, object) 
          {
                if (index == 0)
                {
                /* check if already has rowspan attribtue */
                row_span = jQuery(object).attr('rowspan') ? jQuery(object).attr('rowspan') : 1;

                /* add one */
                row_span++;

                /* include the new rowspan number  */
                jQuery(object).prop('rowspan', row_span);

           }
           else if(index < 2)
           {
                 /* delete the other first name cells */
                 jQuery(object).remove();
           }
        
       });
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: First remove duplicate  values and create group of same value from the source array and create appropriate array structure which help you to create data table structure easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own solution for this problem. It work for me..

```
/*Merging rows Start (updated by Suraj)*/
/*Some changes are made in HTML table's body like adding 'id' property in each column of the table.*/
var row = 0;
var col = 0;

jQuery('tr.tblRow').each(function(n, obj) {
    /*Getting the first row as text*/
    current_name = jQuery(obj).text();

    /*Splitting the above text value into an array using 'Regex' by '/t' and '/n'*/
    var current_name_arr = current_name.split(/\t|\n/);

    /*Now storing the element into an array for getting the values easily.*/
    var current_name_arr1 = [];
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < current_name_arr.length; i++) {
        if(current_name_arr[i] == ""){}
        else {
            current_name_arr1[j] = current_name_arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    /*Setting column*/
    if(n == 0) {
        col = current_name_arr1.length;
    }
});

jQuery('tr.tblRow').each(function(n, obj) {
    var ele = ""
    var removingEle = "";

    /*Merging the cells by spaning the cells and removing the duplicate cells*/
    for(var l = 0; l < col - 1; l++) {
        if(l == 4 || l == 5) {
            continue;
        }
    
        /*Getting the element by id*/
        ele = $("#pdtDetail" + row + l);
        /*Getting the removing element by id*/
        removingEle = $("#pdtDetail" + (row + 1) + l);
    
        if(ele.text() == removingEle.text()) {
            /* check if already has rowspan attribtue */
            row_span = ele.attr('rowspan') ? ele.attr('rowspan') : 1;
            /* add one */
            row_span++;
            /* include the new rowspan number  */
            ele.prop('rowspan', row_span);
        
            
            /* delete the other first name cells */
            removingEle.remove();
        }
    }
    /*If element get matched then increasing row by two because we have to leave the just after commming row.*/
    if(ele.text() == removingEle.text()) {
        row = row + 2;
    }
    else {
        row++;
    }
});
/*Merging rows End*/
```

The Final Table looks like as:

[image]